# How can I remove part of a string in a mysql record?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following code in a `mysql` db and I need to change the `json` code.  I'm trying to find a solution where I can delete the `<script>` tags and everything between them.  I can then use `CONCAT` to add the updated `<script>` content.

How can I delete a partial record?  RLIKE and REGEXP don't seem to do what I need.

Any suggestions?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "Product",
"name": "Birlea Sophia Single Cream Metal Bed Frame",
 "image": [
"http://www.myshop.co.uk/cache/images/products/50265_thumb.jpg",
"http://www.myshop.co.uk/cache/images/products/50265.jpg",
"http://www.myshop.co.uk/cache/images/products/50265_large.jpg"
],
"description": "The Birlea Sophia cream metal bed frame has classic styling with delightful heart details on the head and foot ends and a smooth cream finish.
This bed frame is sturdy in construction and has a sprung slatted base to give any style of mattress the ideal support it needs. The Sophia is also available in a pretty pink finish.
The Sophia from Birlea is a pretty girl&#039;s bed frame and perfect for brightening up any bedroom, so BUY NOW.
Please note: Bed frames are self assembly and priced without a mattress.",
"color": "Cream/Ivory",
"mpn": "SOPB3CRM",
"gtin14": "05060307681031",
"offers": {
"@type": "Offer",
"priceCurrency": "GBP",
"price": "84.97"
},
"brand": {
  "@type": "Thing",
"name": "Birlea"}
}</script> <p style="text-align: justify">The Birlea Sophia cream metal bed frame has classic styling with delightful heart details on the head and foot ends and a smooth cream finish.</p>
<p style="text-align: justify">This&nbsp;bed frame is&nbsp;sturdy in construction and has a sprung slatted base to give any style of mattress the ideal support it needs. The Sophia is also available in a <a href="http://www.myshop.co.uk/Birlea-Sophia-Single-Pink-Metal-Bed-Frame-p1402.html">pretty pink finish</a>.</p>
<p style="text-align: justify">The Sophia from Birlea is a pretty girl's bed frame and perfect for brightening up any bedroom, so <strong><span style="color: #df0000">BUY NOW.</span></strong></p>
<p style="text-align: justify"><b style="text-align: start;">Please note: Bed frames are self assembly and priced without a mattress.</b></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to have a look at the UpdateXML MySQL function (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xml-functions.html#function_updatexml).

Here is an example based on the content you provided.

I put your xml content in the CONTENT column of a XML table:

```
mysql> select CONTENT from XML\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
CONTENT: <script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "Product",
"name": "Birlea Sophia Single Cream Metal Bed Frame",
 "image": [
"http://www.myshop.co.uk/cache/images/products/50265_thumb.jpg",
"http://www.myshop.co.uk/cache/images/products/50265.jpg",
"http://www.myshop.co.uk/cache/images/products/50265_large.jpg"
],
"description": "The Birlea Sophia cream metal bed frame has classic styling with delightful heart details on the head and foot ends and a smooth cream finish.
This bed frame is sturdy in construction and has a sprung slatted base to give any style of mattress the ideal support it needs. The Sophia is also available in a pretty pink finish.
The Sophia from Birlea is a pretty girl&#039;s bed frame and perfect for brightening up any bedroom, so BUY NOW.
Please note: Bed frames are self assembly and priced without a mattress.",
"color": "Cream/Ivory",
"mpn": "SOPB3CRM",
"gtin14": "05060307681031",
"offers": {
"@type": "Offer",
"priceCurrency": "GBP",
"price": "84.97"
},
"brand": {
  "@type": "Thing",
"name": "Birlea"}
}</script> <p style="text-align: justify">The Birlea Sophia cream metal bed frame has classic styling with delightful heart details on the head and foot ends and a smooth cream finish.</p>
<p style="text-align: justify">This&nbsp;bed frame is&nbsp;sturdy in construction and has a sprung slatted base to give any style of mattress the ideal support it needs. The Sophia is also available in a <a href="http://www.myshop.co.uk/Birlea-Sophia-Single-Pink-Metal-Bed-Frame-p1402.html">pretty pink finish</a>.</p>
<p style="text-align: justify">The Sophia from Birlea is a pretty girl's bed frame and perfect for brightening up any bedroom, so <strong><span style="color: #df0000">BUY NOW.</span></strong></p>
<p style="text-align: justify"><b style="text-align: start;">Please note: Bed frames are self assembly and priced without a mattress.</b></p>
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then I used UpdateXML to replace with an empty string every tag matching the "//script" Xpath:

```
mysql> select UpdateXML(CONTENT, '//script', '') as WITHOUT_SCRIPT from XML\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
WITHOUT_SCRIPT:  <p style="text-align: justify">The Birlea Sophia cream metal bed frame has classic styling with delightful heart details on the head and foot ends and a smooth cream finish.</p>
<p style="text-align: justify">This&nbsp;bed frame is&nbsp;sturdy in construction and has a sprung slatted base to give any style of mattress the ideal support it needs. The Sophia is also available in a <a href="http://www.myshop.co.uk/Birlea-Sophia-Single-Pink-Metal-Bed-Frame-p1402.html">pretty pink finish</a>.</p>
<p style="text-align: justify">The Sophia from Birlea is a pretty girl's bed frame and perfect for brightening up any bedroom, so <strong><span style="color: #df0000">BUY NOW.</span></strong></p>
<p style="text-align: justify"><b style="text-align: start;">Please note: Bed frames are self assembly and priced without a mattress.</b></p>
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```